# BigQuery SQL: replace values from a field with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, replace, google-bigquery

Sorry for the long post, just trying to explain the best I can. I'm working with data from Analytics in BigQuery.

This is my initial table:

[image: initial_table]

I had to do some transformations over this to get the last visit of a user by first "filling" out all the gaps from a userID whenever the fullVisitorId is the same and called this new field transformed_userID.

[image: transformed_table]

What I need to get now is the actual segment of the userID: field desired_segment from the image below, which I still haven't managed to get.

This is the logic I'm looking for:
**If the user had a segment different than UNACTIVE --> then retrieve the segment he had in its last visit ignoring all UNACTIVE results. If the user only had an UNACTIVE segment, then UNACTIVE.**

By the way, I tried applying first_value (with help from another post) but its not my ideal result: FIRST_VALUE((segment) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY transformed_userID ORDER BY dateTime desc) *newSegment_transformedUserID*. If I use the initial userID in the over partition by, I get a wrong result as seen in field *newSegment_initialUserID*.

[image: final_table]

I've been trying to get this for hours... :(

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to calculate the transformed column, or the new segment column or both?  Why do you say you want the *previous* value when your example shows data coming both from the past and the future.

Comment: HI @Gordon Linoff! I am trying to calculate the column segment and the final result should be as shown in column desired_segment. The logic is: If the user had a segment different than "unactive" --> then retrieve the segment he had in its last visit ignoring all "unactive" results. If the user only had an "unactive" segment, then "unactive" .

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring `NULL` values, but there are no `NULL` values in this column.  So you need `NULLIF()`:

```
LAST_VALUE(NULLIF(segment, 'UNACTIVE') IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY transformed_userID
    ORDER BY dateTime
   ) as newSegment_transformedUserID
```

If you have multiple conditions, use a `CASE` expression:

```
LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN segment NOT IN ('UNACTIVE') THEN segment END) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (
    PARTITION BY transformed_userID
    ORDER BY dateTime
   ) as newSegment_transformedUserID
```

Comment: Hi!! this one works great!! :) Is there a way of adding several conditions inside NULLIF?? I tried the following inside the nullif but it doesn't work:
NULLIF(segment, 'UNACTIVE', 'UNACTIVE_nonbuyer')